# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf: Set left navigation based on current page

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my Spring MVC application, the left navigation is a Thymeleaf fragment that gets included on all pages via the Layout Dialect Thymeleaf extention. I would like to automatically control the left navigation such that the appropriate nav items are expanded and highlighted based on the current page.

My initial solution is to add logic to the nav fragment that checks a parameter that I set in my controllers. Based on the value in this parameter, nav items know what state they need to be in.

While this approach will work, it seems tedious, especially for those pages where I don't need an actual controller class and the view is set up using the ViewControllerRegistry. Now I'll have to define a mapping method for every page in my application just so I can set the nav parameter. This doesn't seem optimal.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Comment: you could also do this based on the current url. without further modifications spring provides the current page url for the following expression: `${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}`. You could append a class to every nav item based on that. For example if you want to add the class `active` to your nav item if the current url starts with "/test" your expression could look like this: `th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI.startsWith('/test')} ? 'active' : ''"`.

Comment: However this one is not ideal either if you have multiple requestUrls pointing to the same view (as the expression will be pretty long). I don't know if they actually provide a way to look up the view url in a similar way.